# Orthogonal transformation of multivariate Bernoulli-Gaussian distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, independence, signal-processing, correlation

Recently, I studied multivariate Bernoulli-Gaussian distribution which is very useful for sparse signal processing. Suppose $X = (X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n})$ are i.i.d BG($p, \sigma^{2}$), we can know that $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbf{0}$ and Cov($X$) = diag($p \sigma^{2}$). Suppose $A$ is an orthogonal matrix with proper size and $Y = AX$, we can also know that $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbf{0}$ and Cov($Y$) = diag($p \sigma^{2}$). Is it possible for us to know the distribution of $Y$ and is it possible for us to know $Y = (Y_{1}, \cdots, Y_{n})$ are i.i.d? Thank you.

Comment: also asked at https://mathoverflow.net/q/410664/11260